# How to dynamically use eval()

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    <%# Eval(i.ToString()).ToString()%>
}
```

How can I use eval if I don't know the column name. (means if the datatable column is creating dynamically)

1. I am creating a `DataTable`
2. The `dt.Column.Add()` column name will come from database
3. so i dont know what all column name is coming.
4. Now how i can print it in asp.net page. as it Eval require some string constant; `<%# Eval("Column name").ToString()%>`

Comment: what kind of code is that? And what do you want to do(in english)

Comment: i have added explanation of what i exactly doing

Comment: are you using a gridview ?

Comment: If you are trying to do some sort of dynamic grid, you should consider using the 'AutoGenerateColumns' property on the GridView and then leverage the 'OnRowCreated' event to evaluate / transform your data before render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GridView would be much better suited to this, it automatically generates columns from the data source.

You can however loop through the `Columns` property of the `DataTable` and get the `ColumnName` property from each column, however you cannot use a `foreach` loop inside of databinding tags (`<%# %>`).

Here's how to get at the column names in your code-behind:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

//populate data table

foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
    string columnName = col.ColumnName;
}
```

You could use this in a loop in your repeater's item template, however because you aren't using the databinding block (`<%# %>`) you lose `Container.DataItem` which makes it extremely difficult, if not impossible, to render out the data from the current item.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is... you do know what column name is coming. You say in step 2 that the dt.Column.Add() string parameter will come from a database. So that implies a separate process where you go to your database first and get a list of the column names.

You are then going to iterate through this list and populate your Eval function (the FOR statement you have added will actually loop through your list of database column names which might be in an array or a list or their own datatable object).

Comment: ya correct! now my problem is how to get the "Name of the column" of datatable

Answer (score 0):

For your problem

**In **ASP.NET****

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrTester" OnItemDataBound="rptrTester_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptrTesterInner" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("COL_NAME")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**in Code behind C#**

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = null;
    private void GetData()
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dtMain = // MyDAta Table;
        dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("COL_NAME");
        System.Data.DataRow dr = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < dtMain.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = dtMain.Columns[0].ColumnName;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        rptrTester.DataSource = dtMain;
        rptrTester.DataBind();
    }
    protected void rptrTester_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Repeater rptrTesterInner = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptrTesterInner");
        rptrTesterInner.DataSource = dt;
        rptrTesterInner.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: This is not the solution..please read the question before answering :(